# auth = log[0][0] IndexError: list index out of range - ошибка

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, sqlite3

Использую sqlite3 вместе с vk_api. Когда кто-то *второй* пытается взаймодествовать с чат-ботом, возникает ошибка:

```
auth = log[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Код из-за которого возникает ошибка:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT status FROM users WHERE userid = {id}")
               log = cursor.fetchall()
               auth = log[0][0]
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: `print(log)` пробовали выполнить?

Comment: для моей страницы - выводит то, что нужно, если кто-то другой хоть что-то напишет - код прекратится.

Comment: 1) Для получения одного результата лучше используйте `fetchone` 2) Нужно проверять что возвращает база 3) Скорее всего юзера с тем `id` в базе нет

Comment: 100% в базе нет юзера с таким `id`, соответственно возвращает пустой список и получаем ошибку индекса